# left join including where on main table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL (mysql):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS available.*
FROM   available
WHERE `fname` LIKE '%de%'
ORDER BY  `id` asc
```

I want to combine it with

```
LEFT JOIN cart ON available.id = cart.item_id
WHERE cart.item_id IS NULL
```

So that the result gives me only elements which are NOT in the cart table.

Comment: then what seems to be the problem?

Comment: i don't know where to put the join thing in.... :( without the "where fname like xxx" it's no problem.. but with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS available.*
     FROM available
LEFT JOIN cart  
       ON available.id = cart.item_id
    WHERE cart.item_id IS NULL
      AND `fname` LIKE '%de%'
 ORDER BY  `id` asc
```

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505932/left-join-including-where-on-main-table#comment18485848_13505932):

> without the "where fname like xxx" it's no problem.. but with it

Look at [Multiple `WHERE` conditions](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/13)

Comment: Thanks a lot... have just seen.. i had it like that before... but forgot to clean the cart table to get some results... :D And it's working smoooooooooooth :D

Answer (score 0):

You put your joins after your from, and then all your wheres together after that

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS available.*
FROM   available
LEFT JOIN cart ON available.id = cart.item_id
WHERE `fname` LIKE '%de%' AND cart.item_id IS NULL
ORDER BY  `id` asc
```